# Provide/inject axios response

Tags: vue.js, axios

I have one component in which I use axios to get data from API, it works and I can use this data in this component, but when I try to provide this data to another component, I dont get any data there.
Here is part of my code:

```
  data() {
    return {
      theme: [],
    };
  },
  provide() {
   return {
     theme: this.theme
   }
  },
  methods: {
    getTheme() {
      axios
        .get(here is my api url)
        .then((response) => (this.theme = response.data.data));
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.getTheme();
  },
```

and this is the second component:

```
<template>
  <div class="project-wrapper">
    <project-card
    v-for="course in theme.courses"
    :name="course.name"
    :key="course.id"
    ></project-card>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import ProjectCard from "../components/ProjectCard.vue";

export default {
  inject: ["theme"],
  components: {
    ProjectCard,
  }
};
</script>
```

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Is the second component a child of the first one?

Comment: yes, but it is dynamic component

Comment: Could you try this: `theme: Vue.computed(() => this.theme)`?

Comment: how should I import vue in this component? when I tried i got an error that vue is still not defined

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Second option in the [link](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/7017#issuecomment-480906691) may help you

```
provide() {
   return {
     $theme: () => this.theme,
   }
},
```

and

```
inject: ["$theme"],
computed: {
   computedProperty() {
      return this.$theme()
   }
}
```

and

`v-for="course in computedProperty.courses"`

Comment: thank you, i will check the link, it works

Answer (score 0):

When you set `provide` to 'handle' `theme` it adds reactivity to the value of theme - i.e the empty array (`[]`).

If you modify the elements in this array, it will remain reactive - however if you replace the array then the reactivity is broken.

Instead of overwriting `theme` in the `axios` call, try adding the resulting data to it. For example:

```
getTheme() {
  axios
    .get(here is my api url)
    .then((response) => (this.theme.push(...response.data.data));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `theme` to the child component as injected property.

See [Vue.js Docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#provide-inject):

> **The provide and inject bindings are NOT reactive.** This is intentional.
> However, if you pass down an observed object, properties on that
> object do remain reactive.

As inject bindings are not reactive, the changed value of `theme` will not be visible from inside of the child component (it will stay the same as if no axios call happened).

#### Solution 1

Pass the value to the child component as an observed object. It means that in in your `getTheme()` method you will not rewrite the whole property value (`this.theme = ...`) but only write into the object which is already stored in the property (`this.theme.themeData = ...`).

```
data() {
  return {
    theme: { },
  };
},
provide() {
 return {
   theme: this.theme
 }
},
methods: {
  getTheme() {
    axios
      .get(here is my api url)
      .then((response) => (this.theme.themeData = response.data.data));
  },
},
mounted() {
  this.getTheme();
}
```

#### Solution 2

Alternatively you can pass the value to the child component using classical `props` which are always reactive.

Comment: thank u very much for the explanation! now I understand